# Android Studio app (ionic vue + capacitor) is white theme in the emulator but dark in the release

Tags: android, ionic-framework, themes, capacitor

When I build the app with ionic vue + capacitor + android studio the app is shown white background if I run it in the emulator. But if I build for release and publish the app on google play it shows with black background and white text (dark/night theme). How can publish the app with the same theme (white) as I see it in the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a bug on a previous version of System WebView

It's been reported on Ionic and Capacitor repositories
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/24771
https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/5441

Seems fixed on version 98.0.4758.101